# (JS) Markdown issue in flask

Tags: javascript, markdown

I have a small problem with markdown in my flash project.
I want markdown to work for all posts, currently it only works for the first post. I suspect I need to use some kind of loop, but I don't know what to do to make it work.

Code:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    {% for post in document.posts %}
     
    <div class="article-metadata">
      
      <h3><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
      <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</article>
<script>
  const content_text = document.querySelector(".article-content");
  content_text.innerHTML = marked(content_text.innerHTML);
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

[Pic of the posts on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScEsX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` returns the first element with the class. You need to use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements and then use for loop to loop and apply markdown to each element.

```
const content_text = document.querySelectorAll(".article-content");
for (i = 0; i < content_text.length; i++){
      content_text[i].innerHTML = marked(content_text[i].innerHTML);
}
```